# Data not filled automatically in 2nd and 3rd column using select2 while inserting/choosing data in 1st column

Tags: php, dropdown, jquery-select2, codeigniter-3, autofill

I've try to making autofill program using select2 when inserting the first column the second and third column also supposed to filled according to the database but it isn't work. I am using codeigniter 3 and make the form in bootstrap modal. Please check this image: [image: CLICK ME PLEASE] .[image: ME TOO] Anybody can help me please?

Here is my Controller:

```
$this->data['list_proyek'] = array(); 
$data_alokasiproyek = $this->region_model->getAlokasiProyek($filter);
foreach ($data_alokasiproyek as $key => $value) {
  $this->data['list_proyek'][] = array(
    'Kode Proyek'     => $value['Kode Proyek'],
    'Jenis Proyek' => $value['Jenis Proyek'],
    'Nama Proyek'     => $value['Nama Proyek'],
  );
}
```

Here is my model:

```
    public function getAlokasiProyek($filter = array()) {
    $DB2 = $this->load->database('old_db', TRUE);
    $cabang = $this->session->userdata('nama_cabang');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM view_eng_resume_proyek WHERE `Nama Cabang` = '$cabang' AND (`Status Akhir` = 'bast' OR `Status Akhir` = 'commisioning' OR `Status Akhir` = 'start' OR `Status Akhir` = 'reporting' OR `Status Akhir` = 'survey' OR `Status Akhir` = 'operasional')";

    $implode = array();
    
    if (isset($filter['nama_cabang'])) {
        $implode[] = "`Nama Cabang` = '" . $filter['nama_cabang'] . "'";
    }

    if ($implode) {
        $sql .= " AND " . implode(" AND ", $implode);
    }

    $sql .= " ORDER BY `Kode Proyek` DESC";
    // echo $sql;
    $result = $DB2->query($sql)->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

Here is my View:

```
    <label>Kode Proyek</label>
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="Kode_Proyek" name="Kode_Proyek">
  <option value=""></option>
<?php foreach ($list_proyek as $key => $value) : ?>
  <option value="<?= $key ?>">
<?= $value['Kode Proyek'] ?> - <?= $value['Jenis Proyek'] ?> - <?= $value['Nama Proyek'] ?>
  </option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
<input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="hidden" id="tulis_kode_proyek" value="">
<label>Jenis Proyek</label>
<input type="text" value="" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="Jenis_Proyek" id="Jenis_Proyek" required readonly>
<label>Nama Proyek</label>
<input type="text" value="" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="Nama_Proyek" id="Nama_Proyek" required readonly>
<script>
$('#Kode_Proyek').select2({
          dropdownParent: $('#tambahAlokasiHarian'),
          placeholder: 'pilih',
          theme: 'bootstrap4',
          templateResult: function (data, container) {
            if (data.element) {
              $(container).addClass($(data.element).attr("class"));
            }
            return data.text;
          }
      });
      // input select progress on change
      $(document).on('change', '#Kode_Proyek', function() {
        $('#tulis_kode_proyek').val(list_proyek[$(this).val()]['Kode Proyek']);
        $('#Jenis_Proyek').val(list_proyek[$(this).val()]['Jenis Proyek']);
        $('#Nama_Proyek').val(list_proyek[$(this).val()]['Nama Proyek']);
      });
</script>
```